# R - Extract words with a pattern and replace them with the words in inverse order

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string vector of phrases.

```
x <- c("I ate apples 100 already. No apples 50 uhmm" , "He has apples 20 yeah")
```

And I expect the result to be:

```
"I ate 100 apples already. No 50 apples uhmm" , "He has 20 apples yeah"
```

I want to replace de following pattern `"apples \\d{1,4}"` by the reverse order of the found words, in each element of the vector.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `gsub` to capture words as a group (`\\w+`) followed by space and then capture the numbers as another group, replace it with the backreference in reverse order

```
gsub("(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)", "\\2 \\1", x)
#[1] "I ate 100 apples already. No 50 apples uhmm" "He has 20 apples yeah"
```